# Hibernate query for entity with map property

Tags: java, hibernate

I've been struggling with a query in hibernate to update the state of an entity. Such entity, called PaymentRequestLink, is in a one to many relation with another entity called extraparameters

PaymentRequestType.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="payment_link")
public class PaymentRequestLink {

     private Map<String, ExtraParameter<E>> extraParameters;

     @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
     @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
     @CollectionTable(name="extraparameter_payment_link", 
       schema=BaseEntity.DATABASE_SCHEMA, joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="extraparameter_payment_link_id"))
     @MapKeyColumn(name = "name", length=64, nullable = false)
     public Map<String, ExtraParameter<String>> getExtraParameters() {
           return extraParameters;
      }
```

ExtraParameter.java:

```
 @Embeddable
 public class ExtraParameter<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

     //...

     @Column(name="extra_type", length=64, nullable=false)
     @NotNull
     public String getType() {
         return type;
     }

     @Column(name="extra_value", length=255, nullable=false)
     @NotNull
     public T getValue() {
         return value;
     }
```

This is a data example of the extraparameter_payment_link table:

```
extraparameter_payment_link_id  extra_type           extra_value          name
    1                           java.sql.Date        2019-01-01           EXPIRATION_DATE
```

The query I want to make is to update the state of the PaymentRequestLink to EXPIRED when the expiration date, which is stored in the extraparameters, is a date before to the current date.
This is the query I have now:

```
    String stateSentence = "AND state <> '";
    String sqlUpdateLinkDetailed =  "UPDATE PaymentRequestLink ld SET state='EXPIRED' " +
            "WHERE extraParameters.EXPIRATION_DATE.value <= ? " +
            stateSentence + PaymentRequestLinkState.PAID;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
    Timestamp now = new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis());

    hibernateTemplate.bulkUpdate(sqlUpdateLinkDetailed, now);
```

The exception I've got is:

```
 error processing job
 org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: could not resolve property: EXPIRATION_DATE of: component[type,value] [UPDATE 
 com.some.company.PaymentRequestLink ld SET state='EXPIRED' WHERE extraParameters.EXPIRATION_DATE.value <= ? AND state <> 'PAID']; nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: EXPIRATION_DATE of: component[type,value] [UPDATE com.some.company.PaymentRequestLink ld SET state='EXPIRED' WHERE extraParameters.EXPIRATION_DATE.value <= ? AND state <> 'PAID']
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you show the entire ExtraParameter class?

Comment: Is your question answered? If not, please give feedback to enhance the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Elements of indexed collections (arrays, lists, and maps) can be
>   referred to by index in a where clause only:

```
String stateSentence = "AND state <> '";
String sqlUpdateLinkDetailed =  "UPDATE PaymentRequestLink ld SET state='EXPIRED' " +
            "WHERE extraParameters['EXPIRATION_DATE'].value <= ? " +
            stateSentence + PaymentRequestLinkState.PAID;
```

See [HQL expressions documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) for details.